# What kind of cell has the most different receptors?

Tags: human-biology

All hormones and neurotransmittors has their own receptor. Now some of the cells has a few different receptors but others has many sorts of receptors. So what are the most receptive cells? Are that the some braincells?

Comment: I think this is difficult to answer. What is meant by "most receptive" ?  The number of receptors on a cell's surface is known only for a few well studied cases, and many cell surface receptors are not characterized at all, or have not even been discovered. And more receptors does not necessarily translate to a more "sensitive" cell, as receptor sensitivity can be modulated in other ways too.